# Implementing isolation levels for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, isolation-level

I've implemented the 2PC protocol on top of MongoDB as described in MongoDB's [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) and the MongoDB [cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Basically, this works fine: I now have an *all or nothing* semantics, which basically is what I wanted.

Unfortunately, everything now runs with "isolation level" `uncommitted read` (I know that MongoDB does not have isolation level at all, hence the quotes).

What I would do like is to implement the isolation levels `committed read`, `non-repeatable read` and `phantom reads` - and, this would be the optimum - 'serializable' as well.

However, I do not have the slightest idea of how to do this. `Committed read` seems to be the easiest option anyway.

Any ideas, hints, links, ... on where to find additional information on how one could achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can explain the scenarios under which you want these reads to be associated with a specific record? I understand `commited read` (just add this state when the commit is complete for all records properly) however under what curcumstances would the others occur?

Comment: I don't understand your question - do you want to know what I was thinking of when I was writing phantom read, or something more specific?

Comment: Ok I see what isolation you meant now, sorry, gonna need to read up on it a little, it's been a while...